# I want to rename column name in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have column name [car_no] i want to rename it....

I am thinking like this :

```
exec sp_rename 'add_duty_slip.[car_no]' , 'car_no', 'column'
```

but it didn't work.

thanks

Comment: It seems that old name and new name are the same...

Comment: "it didn't work" is not enough to understand your problem. As said, this code won't rename anything. Did you get an error message ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code runs like a charm. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d89cb/1).

But using the same name for both old and new names won't do anything.

With using a different name for both (i.e. actually renaming the column), like :

```
exec sp_rename 'add_duty_slip.[car_no]' , 'car_no1', 'column'
```

works well too. See [this other fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31283/2).

**EDIT** :

In case this is the real meaning of your question, brackets ( `[]` ) are not part of a column name, they're just a delimiter for names containing irregular characters (e.g. spaces). So `[car_no]` and `car_no` is in fact the exact same name.

And in the case your column name is **really** enclosed within brackets, you can do :

```
exec sp_rename 'add_duty_slip."[car_no]"' , 'car_no', 'column'
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05fbe/1).

Comment: So @jbl's comment is more than ever relevant, define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

This would help you.

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Also, Since, both old name and new names are the same, you are unable to notice the change even after you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
EXEC sp_rename 
    @objname = 'table_name.old_column_name', 
    @newname = 'new_column_name', 
    @objtype = 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The script for renaming any column :

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

The script for renaming any object (table, sp etc) :

```
sp_RENAME '[OldTableName]' , '[NewTableName]'
```